# Looping back to the start of a java program after executing a block of code

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I wrote a Java program, more specifically a basic calculator. I want to return to the "main menu", by asking the user to type "0" after solving the math problem. The solution with which I came up with seems to not be working how I want it to be. The concept of the returning is there is a variable "pick" which is at the start of the program and it is not assigned anything yet. The program asks the user what operation he would like to perform, each operation is assigned a number this whole thing is executed with the help of a while/do loop. The loop asks the user what operation they would like to perform while "pick" is 0. If for example, the user picks operation number 2 which is solving a quadratic equation, the value of the variable "pick" changes to 2 and there is an if which is activated if the variable pick is equal to 2 and the block of code which solves the quadratic equation starts executing. After the quadratic equation is solved the program asks the user if they want to get back to the "main menu" by pressing 0 I thought that if the value of the variable "pick" is again 0 the program would start all over again but it doesn't seem to which is the reason I'm writing this.

This is the code:

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String pick_String;
        int pick;
        do {
            pick_String = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Which tool would you like to use? (Type just the number) " +
                    "\n1.Basic Calculator" +
                    "\n2.Solve a quadratic equation" +
                    "\n3.Find a side in a right triangle" +
                    "\n4.Find the distance between two points in a coordinate system" +
                    "\n5.Exit"
            );
            pick = Integer.parseInt(pick_String);
        } while (pick == 0);


        if (pick == 1) {
            //code for the basic calculator
                System.out.println("If you want to get back to the menu type 0");
                pick = scanner.nextInt();
        } else if (pick == 2) {
            //code for solving a the quadratic equation
                System.out.println("If you want to get back to the menu type 0");
                pick = scanner.nextInt();
        } else if (pick == 3) {
            //code for finding a side in a right triangle
                System.out.println("If you want to get back to the menu type 0");
                pick = scanner.nextInt();
        } else if (pick == 4) {
            //code for finding the distance between two points in a coordinate system
                System.out.println("If you want to get back to the menu type 0");
                pick = scanner.nextInt();
        } else if (pick == 5) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

}
```

I thought that it might not work because the program is executed from the top making its way to the bottom and after the "main menu" is executed it can't be done again but I'm not sure.

Comment: Once your program leaves the do/while loop, it will never return to it. You want that loop to encompass your whole program.

Comment: Stepping through your program with the debugger will help you understand what's happening.

Comment: why have four choices that just all do nextInt() ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop which keeps asking for an input as long as the input is 0, but you don't have any if condition that will run the loop again when you're typing 0 later. Like this, you cannot run the loop again by typing 0. Typing 0 after doing one of the calculation will have the same effect as typing any other number greater than 5 or less than 1.
If you want to run the main menu loop when typing 0, you should add an if-condition for this, for example:

```
if (pick == 0) {
    //the main menu loop
}
```

Also, since there comes nothing after the if-else-block, the program will end after you do the next input. You have to loop the program if you want it to run more than once. I suggest turning the do-while-loop into a while-loop and then running the whole code inside a while (true) - loop:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String pick_String;
    int pick = 0;

    while (true) {
 
        if (pick == 0) {
            while (pick==0) {
                pick_String = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Which tool would you like to use? (Type just the number) " +
                "\n1.Basic Calculator" +
                "\n2.Solve a quadratic equation" +
                "\n3.Find a side in a right triangle" +
                "\n4.Find the distance between two points in a coordinate system" +
                "\n5.Exit");
                pick = Integer.parseInt(pick_String);
            }
        }

        if (pick == 1) {
            //code for the basic calculator
            System.out.println("If you want to get back to the menu type 0");
            pick = scanner.nextInt();
        } else if (pick == 2) {
            //code for solving a the quadratic equation
            System.out.println("If you want to get back to the menu type 0");
            pick = scanner.nextInt();
        } else if (pick == 3) {
            //code for finding a side in a right triangle
            System.out.println("If you want to get back to the menu type 0");
            pick = scanner.nextInt();
        } else if (pick == 4) {
            //code for finding the distance between two points in a coordinate system
            System.out.println("If you want to get back to the menu type 0");
            pick = scanner.nextInt();
        } else if (pick == 5) {
            System.exit(0); // this will exit while(true) along with the program
        }
    
    
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much man, you are a lifesaver! Looks like I need to redo the while loop course :D